# Error : Unknown column 'codigo' in 'field list' con cuatro tablas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo cuatro tablas, una de alumnos tal que cada uno toma una o mas asignaturas, otra de asignaturas que tienen uno o mas alumnos y solo la puede dar un profesor, otra de profesores que puede dar mas de una asignatura, y otra de alumnos_asignaturas, esta ultima tiene las llaves foráneas de alumnos y asignaturas, pues sale de una relación Muchos-Muchos, lo que quiero es mostrar en una sola tabla el nombre del alumno, el nombre de la asignatura y el nombre del profesor, lo estoy intentando con INNER JOIN, en el primer ejemplo logro mostrar una tabla con nombres de alumnos y el código de la clase, pero en el segundo ya no puedo agregar los datos de la tabla de asignatura, ya que me aparece error "unkown column "asignatura.nombre_asg"in "field list"", si me pudiesen ayudar para poder unir estas cuatro tablas, por favor.

Esta sí funciona:

```
SELECT al.nombre_al,aya.codigo_asig1     
FROM alumno as al    
INNER JOIN alumnos_asig as aya    
ON al.n_matricula = aya.n_matricula1;
```

Esta no funciona:

```
SELECT al.nombre_al, asignatura.nombre_asg     
FROM alumno as al    
INNER JOIN alumnos_asig as aya    
ON al.n_matricula = aya.n_matricula1    
INNER JOIN alumnos_asig as aya2    
ON asignatura.codigo_asig = aya2.codigo_asig1;
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu segundo INNER JOIN estas tratando de referenciar a una tabla que no esta previamente definida en el contexto. porque haces 2 INNER JOIN a la misma tabla que es alumnos_asig pero referencias a asignatura.codigo_asig y esta no esta referenciada en el contexto

```
INNER JOIN alumnos_asig as aya ON al.n_matricula = aya.n_matricula1
INNER JOIN alumnos_asig as aya2 ON asignatura.codigo_asig = aya2.codigo_asig1;
```

Desconosco las tablas pero creo que el INNER JOIN deberia de ser con asignatura atravez de alumnos_asig

```
SELECT 
    al.nombre_al, 
    asig.nombre_asg
FROM alumno as al
INNER JOIN alumnos_asig as aya ON al.n_matricula = aya.n_matricula1
INNER JOIN asignatura as asig ON asig.codigo_asig = aya.codigo_asig1;
```

Comment: Sí me funcionó, Muchísimas gracias!